# When creating data in MongoDB, there was an automatically generated value, how can I control it?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository, mongo-collection

First, I will show you two pictures of data recorded in MongoDB Compass.

### [User Collection]

[image]

### [Plan Collection]

[image]

As you can see I get only 3 values ​​from the user in the `User collection`: `name`, `phone` and `address`. It is understood that `_id` is automatically generated through `ObjectID` when such information is received, but I do not know why `_class` is created. When `_class` contains user information that I created myself, class information for use is entered as a string value. ex) "com.example.User".
Plan collection also receives 11 data from `index` to `createdAt` from the user, and `_id` is automatically generated through `ObjectID`. But here we get `__v` instead of `_class`, and this value will always exist as 0.

For reference, I did not implement the way the Plan Collection is saved, but I implemented the way the User Collection is saved through Spring boot.My Repository Interface looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

1. Is the creation of `_class` a result of using MongoRepository?
2. Are `__v` or `_class` necessary values?
3. How can I get rid of it if I don't need it?
4. Can developers change the name themselves?

Comment: `_class` is meta-data used by Spring Data MongoDB to map the MongoDB collection document fields to the Java POJO class fields in your Spring application. I believe there are settings in Spring to work with it and its configuration.